# Alternative to Kdeconnect?

Tags: kde-connect

I am using Ubuntu MATE and while trying to download `kdeconnect`, I found that it tries to pull about 150MB of plasma dependencies along with it. Why is it like that? I don't even think `breeze` and `breeze-icon-theme` should be a dependency. I am no expert but it just seems wrong to me. Is there no GTK-based alternative that does the same things as kdeconnect?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu

Comment: @CelticWarrior that link doesn't provide an alternative that doesn't require installing 150MB of KDE packages as far as I can tell.

Comment: There is [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com), an app on your mobile phone that talks to your PC, either to a browser plugin or to a stand-alone application [PB for desktop](https://github.com/sidneys/pb-for-desktop/releases).

Comment: @Jos I know pushbullet but it is free neither as in beer nor as in speech.

Comment: That is simply not true. I use Pushbullet on several devices and I have never paid anything. If you wanted open source solutions only, you should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Jos Pushbullet has file size limits. So no, it is not free. Secondly, I want something that works over local network only.

Comment: https://github.com/bboozzoo/mconnect. Mconnect but nobody wants to give it any help or love. Wish it would though

Answer (score 4):

There is [Mconnect](https://github.com/bboozzoo/mconnect)

## EDIT May, 2018

A new comer is [GSConnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/) for gnome 3.24+. More informations on their GitHub.